# Seleccionar ref que se encuentra en un componente Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, component

Tengo un input tipo file en un componente de una aplicacion vue y necesito poder acceder a desde la aplicacion y no quisiera usar vuex ni javascript para ello.

Si el ref estuviera en el root del app, simplemente seria escribir algo así desde la consola:

```
app.$refs.nombreRef.files o app.$refs.nombreRef.files[0]
```

Desde la aplicacion puedo acceder al ref mediante este código:

```
this.$refs.nombreRef.files[0]
```

Si el ref estuviera en un componente(este es mi caso particular), desde la consola puedo acceder a él mediante el siguiente código

```
app.$children[0].$refs.NombreRef.files[0]
```

Desde javascript debería funcionar algo así
         `var x = document.querySelector('#ejemplo')`
Donde ejemplo seria el id del input en el componente

Pero no sé acceder al ref desde la aplicacion, supuse que este código funcionaría, pero no lo hace:

```
this.$children[0].$refs.NombreRef.files[0]
```

Muchas gracias por cualquier sugerencia.

Comment: Si ya puedes acceder al `ref`, haz lo mismo pero desde tu componente y listo, no termino de entender el problema. ¿Puedes explicarlo más?

Comment: Necesito verificar si se ha cargado un archivo para poder habilitar un boton. Puedo enviar el archivo cargado a la base de datos por medio de este codigo ```this.$refs.nombreRef.files[0]```, pero para verificar que esta cargado no me deja hacerlo

Comment: Hace cosa de un año, tuve el mismo problema que tienes ahora. Recuerdo que lo solucioné con un ref, pero ahora no se decirte cómo. Creo que con un on change en el input o algo asi. No recuerdo bien.

Comment: O sea, se carga algo en un componente hijo, y en lugar de levantar un evento que le avise al padre, queres hacer que cosa?

Comment: Tengo este codigo ```<input type="file" ref="nombre" @change="verificar">```, verificar es un metodo, el cual tiene este codigo: ```if(this.$refs.nombre.files[0]){this.habilitar = this.$refs.nombre.files.length}```, tons si this.habilitar es mayor que 0, me habilita el boton de envio

Comment: Prueba con esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45179061/file-input-on-change-in-vue-js/45179094

Comment: Muchas gracias por todas las sugerencias, ya pude resolver: como podia enviar el archivo a la base de datos, dije... si creo esto, ```if(this.$refs.nombreRef.files){this.habilitar = 1}``` y mediante esta simple linea de codigo, resolvi mi problema de validacion